# Altering fabcar example hyperledger-fabric

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I have been playing around with the hyperledger-fabric samples/fabcar example for a while and I am able to add more fields and functions in the fabcar.go but when I change the fields entirely. I am getting errors in deployment.

Here is an example of the changes I have made in fabcar.go.

```
type Car struct {
Name  string `json:"Name"`
College  string `json:"College"`
DOB  string `json:"DOB"`
SecretCode  string `json:"SecretCode"`
    }

func (s *SmartContract) initLedger(APIstub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) sc.Response {
cars := []Car{
    Car{Name: "name1", College: "college1", DOB: "dob1", SecretCode: "secretcode1"},
    Car{Name: "name2", College: "college2", DOB: "dob2", SecretCode: "secretcode2"},
    Car{Name: "name3", College: "college3", DOB: "dob3", SecretCode: "secretcode3"},
    Car{Name: "name4", College: "college4", DOB: "dob4", SecretCode: "secretcode4"},
    }
i := 0
for i < len(cars) {
    fmt.Println("i is ", i)
    carAsBytes, _ := json.Marshal(cars[i])
    APIstub.PutState("CAR"+strconv.Itoa(i), carAsBytes)
    fmt.Println("Added", cars[i])
    i = i + 1
}

return shim.Success(nil)
}
```

Here is the error that I get when I run startFabric.sh:

```
>Error: Error endorsing chaincode: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error starting container: Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 2 "# github.com/fabcar
chaincode/input/src/github.com/fabcar/fabcar.go:132: unknown Car field 'Make' in struct literal
chaincode/input/src/github.com/fabcar/fabcar.go:132: unknown Car field 'Model' in struct literal
chaincode/input/src/github.com/fabcar/fabcar.go:132: unknown Car field 'Colour' in struct literal
chaincode/input/src/github.com/fabcar/fabcar.go:132: unknown Car field 'Owner' in struct literal
chaincode/input/src/github.com/fabcar/fabcar.go:193: car.Owner undefined (type Car has no field or method Owner)
chaincode/input/src/github.com/fabcar/fabcar.go:211: car.Colour undefined (type Car has no field or method Colour)
"
```

I am using Mac OSX yosemite and I have tried cleaning the docker by removing all the data and starting again and I have also tried renaming the go file but nothing works. What am I doing wrong here?

output of go build command:

```
>go build
../../../../../go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer/admin.pb.go:74:8: use of vendored package not allowed
../../../../../go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer/admin.pb.go:77:8: use of vendored package not allowed
../../../../../go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer/chaincode.pb.go:9:8: use of vendored package not allowed
../../../../../go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer/init.go:21:2: use of vendored package not allowed
../../../../../go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/bccsp/pkcs11/conf.go:25:2: use of vendored package not allowed
../../../../../go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer/admin.pb.go:80:2: use of vendored package not allowed
../../../../../go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer/admin.pb.go:81:2: use of vendored package not allowed
../../../../../go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/flogging/grpclogger.go:21:2: use of vendored package not allowed
```

Comment: can you run "go build" to compile your chaincode and extend your questions with output?

Comment: I have updated my question with the go build output.

Comment: what is the purpose of using anything from admin.pb.go file?

Comment: I am not sure. I did not make any changes to fabcar.go other than mentioned above.

Comment: did you run go build from chaincode folder? E.g. "cd chaincode/fabcar" and "go build"? There is no vendoring folders inside fabrcar chaincode example.

Comment: When I have v0.6 of hyperledger fabric then I get the error - cannot find package "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer". Then I manually searched this folder in https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric and downloaded the release option and then I get the vendor error. Even in the original fabcar.go samething happens.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you having a compilation error, while you changed structure of the `Car` to be

```
type Car struct {
     Name        string `json:"Name"`
     College     string `json:"College"`
     DOB         string `json:"DOB"`
     SecretCode  string `json:"SecretCode"`
}
```

While many function remained in `fabcar.go` are still trying to use this struct "old fashion" way, assuming previous model:

```
type Car struct {
        Make   string `json:"make"`
        Model  string `json:"model"`
        Colour string `json:"colour"`
        Owner  string `json:"owner"`
}
```

For example:

```
func (s *SmartContract) createCar(APIstub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, args []string) sc.Response {

        if len(args) != 5 {
                return shim.Error("Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting 5")
        }

        var car = Car{Make: args[1], Model: args[2], Colour: args[3], Owner: args[4]}

        carAsBytes, _ := json.Marshal(car)
        APIstub.PutState(args[0], carAsBytes)

        return shim.Success(nil)
}
```

I would suggest instead reusing declaration of `Car` struct just create your own and use it properly:

```
type Student struct {
     Name        string `json:"Name"`
     College     string `json:"College"`
     DOB         string `json:"DOB"`
     SecretCode  string `json:"SecretCode"`
}
```

And

```
func (s *SmartContract) initLedger(APIstub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) sc.Response {
   cars := []Student{
    Student{Name: "name1", College: "college1", DOB: "dob1", SecretCode: "secretcode1"},
    Student{Name: "name2", College: "college2", DOB: "dob2", SecretCode: "secretcode2"},
    Student{Name: "name3", College: "college3", DOB: "dob3", SecretCode: "secretcode3"},
    Student{Name: "name4", College: "college4", DOB: "dob4", SecretCode: "secretcode4"},
    }
   i := 0
   for i < len(cars) {
      fmt.Println("i is ", i)
      carAsBytes, _ := json.Marshal(cars[i])
      APIstub.PutState("CAR"+strconv.Itoa(i), carAsBytes)
      fmt.Println("Added", cars[i])
      i = i + 1
   } 

   return shim.Success(nil)
}
```

Comment: Hi Artem, I did make a totally seperate file but when I do startFabric for it then it still deploys the original fabcar.go. Here is the link to the file. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_DLPu5PlCiFQ25ZTFBtUnh4aTQ

Comment: well, you need to adapt startFabric.sh script to use your new chaincode, it designed to demo fabrcar only

Comment: I did that too. Here is the StartFabric.sh file as well. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_DLPu5PlCiFZFI0UkFhVVNkSUk               cli peer chaincode install -n FirstApp -v 1.0 -p github.com/fabcar. Can you tell me where this github.com/fabcar is present?

Comment: you can find it here: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release/chaincode/fabcar

Comment: cli peer chaincode install -n FirstApp -v 1.0 -p github.com/fabcar. Do I need to replace github.com/fabcar to github.com/FirstApp or it remains the same?

Comment: Hard to tell with partial data about your experiment.

Comment: instead of altering can you just try to implement chaincode of your own?

Comment: I will give it a shot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

well, check this link [fabcar.go chaincode of hyperledger does not accept the changes and modification and always run previous chaincode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55331334/fabcar-go-chaincode-of-hyperledger-does-not-accept-the-changes-and-modification/56731068#56731068), u will find the answer there, when u interact with the source code, don't forget to delete its previously used modules to completely imply ur code change!